# Uniform convergence and sequences of minima

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$,  $f \in C(\Omega)$ and $g \in C^1(\Omega)$ and assume that $f - g$ has a *strict global minimum* at $x \in \Omega$.

Is the following true?

> there exists a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly $\implies$ there is a sequence of points $x_n \to x$ such that $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$ and  $f_n - g$ has a global minimum at $x_n$?

Comment: By strict global minimum of $h$, do you mean: $h(x) < h(x')$ for any $x' \neq x$? 
Is $\Omega$ bounded? (It seems to me you could construct $f - g$ with almost-minima receding into $\infty$ that would make a counter-example possible.)

Comment: I suggest to simplify the question by assuming wlog that $g = 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ (and maybe $x = 0$).

Comment: You could add an unbounded term to the $ f_n $ sequence, so that uniform convergence is preserved but since it is unbounded you cannot have a minimum. It may be true that there exists a subsequence of $ f_n $ that verifies your claim though.

Comment: @user66081: You can assume that $g=0$ and $x=0$, but you need the assumption that $f$ has a strict minimum at $x$.

Comment: Note that if $ \Omega $ is compact then my argument is false, so that hypothesis could also make the statement true.

Comment: Anyway, this is a standard lemma in the theory of viscosity solutions (see e.g. the book of Bardi - Capuzzo Dolcetta, "Optimal control...", Lemma 2.4).

Comment: @Rigel Lemma 2.4 refers to local minima.

Comment: @Rene: you are right, I missed the last "global". At first sight, if $\Omega$ is unbounded, the result need not be true.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample for $\Omega = (-\pi, \pi):$ Define $f(x) = \sin^2(x),g\equiv 0.$ Then $f$ has a strict global minimum at $0.$

For $n=1,2,\dots ,$ let $\varphi_n$ be the piecewise linear function on $[-\pi,\pi]$ whose graph connects the points $(-\pi,-1), (-\pi+1/n,1), (\pi-1/n,1), (\pi,-1).$ On $(-\pi, \pi),$ set $f_n = \varphi_nf.$ Do a little work to see $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $(-\pi,\pi).$

For each $n,$ the global minimum value of $f_n$ on $\Omega$ is negative and occurs twice, once to the left of $-\pi/2,$ once to the right of $\pi/2.$ So it is impossible to find $x_n \to 0$ such that $f_n$ has a global minimum at $x_n.$

Comment: What other hypotheses can I add to make the statement hold true?

Comment: Note that this example also works with the compact set $\Omega=[-\pi,+\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Omega$ is unbounded the result is not true.
Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, $g=0$, $x=0$, and consider the function
$$
f(x) = x^2 e^{-x^2}
$$
which has a strict minimum point at $x=0$.
Let $h(x):= \min\{x^2-1, 0\}$ and define
$$
f_n(x) := f(x) + \frac{1}{n}\, h(x-n).
$$
It is clear that the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$.
On the other hand, since $f_n(n) = n^2 e^{-n^2} - 1/n < 0$ for $n$ large enough, the function $f_n$ attains its global minimum at a point $x_n \in (n-1, n+1)$.

Comment: But $ g \not \in C^1(\Omega) $ at $ -1 $ and $ 1 $.

Comment: Sorry, I called $g$ an auxiliary function (now is $h$).

Comment: What other hypotheses can I add to make the statement hold true?